How to make React project open up Index.Js components Instead of Index.html
I'm a beginner to React and I wanted to use React on the frontend. For some reason, every time I run 'npm start', it keeps routing to my public/index.html file rather than my index.js file which has all the components I want to run.
Code:
package.json
 "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "^1.3.8",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "base64id": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.3.5",
    "engine.io": "^6.5.5",
    "engine.io-parser": "^5.2.2",
    "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.24.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "socket.io-adapter": "^2.5.5",
    "socket.io-parser": "^4.2.4",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "undici-types": "^5.26.5",
    "vary": "^1.1.2",
    "ws": "^8.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start src/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build src/index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

index.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import './App.css';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename="http://localhost:3000/">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        {/* Add more routes as needed */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;

I've been trying a number of different things like deleting package.json and lock and then reinstalling, commenting out appHtml from paths.json, etc. When I run npm start, I just want it to route strictly to index.js where I handle my other routes (i.e. '/' loads my HomePage.js file).
However, when I load my react project on the browser and check inspect element -> network, I see that it's clearly hitting my index.html page (which is all commented out for now), so I just see a blank page on localhost:3000/. Any suggestions? Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something about React as I'm still learning :)

"every time I run 'npm start', it keeps routing to my public/index.html" - This is correct. Browsers are served HTML files, and the HTML files can load Javascript files, e.g. your index.js file that should be the file that imports the App component and renders it to the DOM. You appear to be missing React basics, which is way more than what can be covered in one SO post, so I suggest starting at the beginning: https://react.dev/learn.

@DrewReese thanks for the tip :) so essentially youre staying within index.html, i can then write some code to route to index.js? off first glance, does my index.js make sense?

also how come ive seen people do tutorials/have github projects where do they're interacting with index.js directly rather than index.html?

Welcome to World of ReactJS!
Use this :


"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },



Instead of :


"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start src/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build src/index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },



I would suggest to remove the "src/index.js" in start and build of the scripts.
Also, I assume your HomePage component is not empty and it has some data to display. Incase of empty then it would show blank page.
Happy learning!

You have a misunderstanding or you just haven't progressed far enough into a tutorial or setup guide to understand that you use both. index.html and index.js are served to the client, the index.js file uses react-dom and mounts the React app into a div rendered in index.html. If your app uses client-side routing, then once the app is mounted and rendered then it can finally take effect, i.e. synchronize the UI to the URL path in the case of a BrowserRouter.
You should have:

/public/index.html - This is generally automatically generated for you and you don't typically need to edit it unless you have specific need to set global page configurations or external (to React) 3rd-party libraries. A typical file might look like the following:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
</html>


/src/index.js - This is the entry point file that generally imports the App component and creates the root React node that "injects", or mounts, the React app into the specified DOMNode rendered in index.html. Note above the "The build step will place the bundled scripts into the  tag." comment, meaning your build process will inject a script tag there that loads your index.js file. A basic index.js file may look like the following:
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App"; // <-- "/src/App.jsx"

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

Similarly you typically won't need to edit this file much unless you wish to render your global context providers here, e.g. Redux Provider, React-Router-DOM BrowserRouter, etc

/src/App.jsx - From here your App file component will have the entirety of your React app code. For example yours may be written as:
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        {/* Add more routes as needed */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


package.json - Your scripts should just be the default react-scripts scripts that load the index.html file.
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
}




Also how come I've seen people do tutorials/have Github projects where
do they're interacting with index.js directly rather than index.html?

For demo purposes they may just be writing all the JSX they wish to demonstrate directly in index.js. Tutorials are notorious for taking shortcuts and not fully explaining the common standard industry best practices, you might just think of them as "quick & dirty" demonstrations.
Example:
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        {/* Add more routes as needed */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);

This is valid, but as your app grows in size you'll likely want to adhere to the common practice of separate index.js and App.jsx root files, one for rendering the app into the DOM, the other for collecting the root React components (global contexts like Redux, theme providers, query contexts, etc...) and rendering the React UI.

wow this was great, thank you so much. will learn more from react documentation but I'm understanding it more conceptually :)
